# How to replace transaction by something other than transaction_hash?

Tags: python, python-3.x, solidity, web3py

I'm using a Python + web3 script that sends a transaction from addr1 to addr2.
I want to replace this transaction from another script (home computer vs server) so it's difficult for me to get the transaction hash and use eth.replace_transaction()) with the pending transaction's gasPrice * 1.125.

How can I replace the transaction? I know its nonce and its source and destination adresses but not the hash (because I'm missing the exact gasPrice used).

Can I get the transaction from the blockchain by nonce and block or is there some other way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Transactions are processed by the nonce, not by hash.

Broadcast a valid transaction with the same nonce, but higher gas, to replace a transaction. In the case miners see two valid competing transactions with the same nonce, they usually pick one with the lower nonce (not guaranteed though).

Comment: I'm trying to do that but how can I get the original gas price? (I have the nonce but not the gas that was calculated on the other script).

Comment: You get the hash when before broadcast the transaction. Please edit your question and add relevant source code, so it is easy to point out how to get the hash.

Comment: When I try to send a transaction, I get: "Error sending the txn the second time: {'code': -32000, 'message': 'replacement transaction underpriced'}" but the first sending didn't happen using this script on my computer, it happened on my server using another script. So I can't get the info from my code but since I get this error I know the nonce is good. My quest is to get the gasPrice of the transaction that's already pending on the eth block so I can add more for mine. I have the nonce for this and the src/dst address.